# Protobuf ParseDelimitedFrom implementation in C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, poco, protobuf-net

C# Publisher is publishing continuos marketdata messages in custom protobuff format over the socket using "writeDelimitedTo" API. I have to read all messages in C++ and desearialize it. Below is my code. Since C++ don't have "parseDelimitedFrom", so have coded something like below after going through multiple suggestions in this forum.

Now my question is - Refering to the code below, If the first message size is less than 1024 then in the first iteration, i will have full stream of the 1st message and part of the stream from the 2nd message. After deserializing first message, How can i read remaining streams of the second message from socket and merge it with the stream which i read in the previous iteration ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:** [Support for "delimited" format is now part of the official protobuf library.](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/util/delimited_message_util.h) The post below predates it being added.

I've written optimally-efficient versions of `parseDelimitedFrom` and `writeDelimitedTo` in C++ here (the `read` and `write` methods of `Uncompressed`):

https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/blob/06a7136708955d91f8ddc1fa3d54e620eacba13e/c%2B%2B/src/benchmark/protobuf-common.h#L101

Feel free to copy.

These implementations read from / write to a `ZeroCopyInputStream` / `ZeroCopyOutputStream`.(Hmm, for some reason my `write` is declared to use `FileOutputStream`, but you should be able to just change that to `ZeroCopyOutputStream`.)

So, you'll need to create a `ZeroCopyInputStream` which reads from your `StreamSocket`, then pass it to my `read()`.

It looks like `StreamSocket` is a classic copying-read interface.  You should therefore use `CopyingInputStreamAdaptor` as your `ZeroCopyInputStream`, wrapping an implementation of `CopyingInputStream` which reads from your `StreamSocket`.

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.io.zero_copy_stream_impl_lite#CopyingInputStreamAdaptor

Comment: @RakeshKumar - The best way to thank someone for their answer is to accept and/or upvote it.  :)

Comment: the awesome code is 404 not found at github anymore : (

Comment: @ZFY Fixed the link.